# New class instance inherts previous instance values

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am writing a small tree class that implements a doubly linked list:

```
class node(object): 
def __init__(self, level=0, pieces=0, parent=None,
             root=None, childNo=None, avgN=2): 

    self.level       = level   # Current level in the tree. Zero = top.
    self.pieces      = pieces  # Number of children. Can be constant or Poisson chosen random.
    self.parent      = parent  # Parent of this node.
    self.child       = {}      # Children of this node. Using a dictionary means
                               # the root could have direct access\
                               # to all children.
    self.childrenID  = {}
    self.myID        = childNo # This node's index in the parents self.child list.

    if (root == None):         # If I'm the root, then hey, I'm the root!
        self.root   = self
    else:
        self.root   = root

    self.avgN          = avgN
    self.numOfChildren = 0
    self.pieces        = self.avgN



def print_all_data(self):
    print "Printing all data for node:",self.myID
    obj_attr = [a for a in dir(n) if not a.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(n,a))]
    for ob in obj_attr:
        print ob, getattr(n,ob)
    return


# This function acutally adds a child node to this parent.
def add_child_node(self, childno):

    self.numOfChildren        += 1
    if (self.numOfChildren > self.pieces):
        print "Error: number of children exceeds the number of assigned pieces"
        print "       for node:", self.myID

    childno                             = self.compute_new_child_ID(self.level, self.numOfChildren)
    self.childrenID[self.numOfChildren] = childno
    self.child[childno]                 = self.get_new_node(childno)

    return

def get_new_node(self,childno):

    return node(level=self.level+1, parent=self,
                root=self.root, childNo=childno,
                avgN=self.avgN)

def compute_new_child_ID(self, level, childno):
    return (level+1)*100 + childno
def get_child_no_from_child_ID(self, level, childID):
    return childID - (level+1)*100
```

Note some of the functionality looks duplicated, but those are placeholders for future use.

Now if I make an instance I get:

```
n = node()
n.print_all_data()

Printing all data for node: None
avgN 2
child {}
childrenID {}
level 0
myID None
numOfChildren 0
parent None
pieces 2
root <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc0ae10>
```

However adding any children results in them inhereting the properties of the parent:

```
n.add_child_node(0)
n.add_child_node(1)
n.print_all_data()

Printing all data for node: None
avgN 2
child {101: <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc46350>, 102: <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc460d0>}
childrenID {1: 101, 2: 102}
level 0
myID None
numOfChildren 2
parent None
pieces 2
root <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc0ae10>
```

Here's the child data:

```
n.child[101].print_all_data()

Printing all data for node: 101
avgN 2
child {101: <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc46350>, 102: <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc460d0>}
childrenID {1: 101, 2: 102}
level 0
myID None
numOfChildren 2
parent None
pieces 2
root <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc0ae10>
```

Also creating a new node inherits this old instance data:

```
n2 = node()
n2.print_all_data()

Printing all data for node: None
avgN 2
child {101: <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc46350>, 102: <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc460d0>}
childrenID {1: 101, 2: 102}
level 0
myID None
numOfChildren 2
parent None
pieces 2
root <__main__.node object at 0x7fb33dc0ae10>
```

Now I've searched all over StackOverflow and I'm not [failing to use init (these are instance attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances) nor am I [improperly initializing an immutable dictionary in the function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453008/new-instance-has-old-instance-attribute-values) (further explained [here](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)). I couldn't find any other example in SO that matched my issue, hence the new question. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please check the help article [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instances are right, you're just printing wrong data.

In the method `print_all_data`, you're always printing attributes of the **instance referenced by the variable `n`** (which is inherited from the higher scope and it always references your "root" node no matter in what instance it's used) instead of printing attributes of the current instance (`self` reference).

In the method `print_all_data`, you need something like this (**current instance is referenced by the variable `self`**):

```
obj_attr = [a for a in dir(self)
            if not a.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(self, a))]
```